# Where binary is extracted to, in a self contained executable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.0

With the release of .Net Core 3.0, there is a new option that allow you to publish executable as a single file executable. My question is: Where the executable extract it's content for later execution.

I mean it's a random location? Or it's a identifiable random location like `%AppData%/Local/{AssemblyName}/{UUID}/` or something on does line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thoughts. I ended up logging the location, using this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Assembly Location: {Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location}");
```

It seems that, they choose a pseudo random location, like I thought.
In this case mine was: `%AppData%\Local\Temp\.net\{AssemblyName}\{UUID}\{AssemblyName}.dll`